# SystemTap: how to reset an aggregate

Tags: linux

I've been playing around with SystemTap and came across a question that I could not find an answer for in the documentation.  The SystemTap languages specifies an "aggregate" datatype that can be used to accumulate data.  I am trying to write a script that will aggregate vfs reads and writes and then print out the sum of that aggregate every 5 seconds.  However, I would like to reset the aggregate once I have printed out the sum so that I essentially get 5-second snapshots of IO activity instead of a full-session sum of IO.  Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
probe vfs.read.return {
    vfs_writes <<< $return
}
probe timer.s(5) {
    printf("vfs_writes: %d", @sum(vfs_writes))
}
```

My question is: how can I reset (in this example) the vfs_writes aggregate after I print out it's sum?

Answer (score 2):

Even though the vfs_writes is a scalar you should be able to use the "delete" on it. So the following script will operate in the manner you desire:

```
global vfs_writes

probe vfs.read.return {
    vfs_writes <<< $return
}
probe timer.s(5) {
    printf("vfs_writes: %d\n", @sum(vfs_writes))
    delete vfs_writes
}
```